# Проверка наличия элементов в обоих списках с переводом в нижний регистр

Tags: python

```
current_users=['sam','karl','john','ann','helen']
new_users=['thomas','Karl','Helen','ilia','alex']
for new_user in new_users:
    if current_users in new_users:
        print("You can't choose that name")
    else:
        print("You can choose that name")
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы перебирались списки, а потом выводилось одно из двух сообщений.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, вы хотите проверить встречаются ли имена из `new_users` в списке `current_users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во время проверки на вхождение элементов в другой список вы можете использовать метод [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) для перевода в нижний регистр:

```
current_users=['sam','karl','john','ann','helen']
new_users=['thomas','Karl','Helen','ilia','alex']

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in current_users:
        print("You can't choose that name")
    else:
        print("You can choose that name")
```

Также вы можете сначала создать список с элементами в нижнем регистре и делать обычную проверку:

```
new_users_lowercase = [user.lower() for user in new_users]

for new_user in new_users_lowercase:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print("You can't choose that name")
    else:
        print("You can choose that name")
```